# Passing data from view to view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am making an application solely for the purpose of learning more objective c. This application basically takes a user to a modal view and then gives the user options (uibuttons) to click. When a user taps a button, the modal view is dismissed and I would like to take the data taken from that button (whether it's the title of the button, tag, etc, whichever is easiest to use) and store it as a variable in my main view. I have tried using an extern NSString defined in a seperate .h file, but no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: Please put your code so that we could help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go through delegate pattern in iOS.

You can pass the value back to the main view using delegate methods.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html) on Protocols.

[Example using Protocol](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

Answer (score 1):

use delegations. make a protocol.

```
@protocol SelectValueDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) selectedValue:(NSString * )values selectionViewController:(UIViewController *)controller;
- (void)selectionCanceled:(UIViewController *)controller;
@end
```

implement it inside your `MainViewController.h`

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController<SelectValueDelegate> {
    //.... 
}
```

and `.m` file looks like this:

```
- (void) selectedValue:(NSString * )values selectionViewController:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    //here you have value.
    [controller dissmissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)selectionCanceled:(UIViewController *)controller
{
        [controller dissmissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and in you `ModalViewController` make a property of delegate like this:

```
@interface ModalViewController : UIViewController
        id<SelectValueDelegate> delegate;
}
@property(assign)id delegate; // synthesize it also
```

now on click of button do something like this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
       [delegate selectedValue:@"Value" selectionViewController:self];
}
```

and when presenting it modally inside `MainViewController`, do something like this:

```
ModalViewController *screen = [[ModalViewController alloc] initWithBlahblah];
screen.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a try--It looks straightforward and useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the delegate methods to pass value see Apple documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in an object in the appDelegate which is the Delegate file for the applications,

You can declare an object in appDelegate:

```
NSString *buttonName;
```

Then propertise and synthesise that object.

After doing this, put a code in the View Controller which you are opening as a Modal VIew:

```
appDelegate.buttonName = yourbutton.titleLabel.text;
```

Now even after dismissing the modal view, you'll be having the button's title stored in the appldelegate's object, and you can access it from any where in your application.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you've two viewcontrollers say **A** & **B**

**Your A.h**

```
{
  NSString *strData;
  int cId;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strData;
@property (readwrite) int cId;
```

**Now In your A.m**

```
@synthesize strData,cId;
```

**Your B.h**

```
@class A

{
   A *aObj;
}
```

**Now In your B.m**

```
#import "A.h"

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
  aObj=[A alloc] init]; //alloc object of A
  [aObj setCId:10]; //set value for cId
  [aObj setStrData:@"Hello from B"]; //set value for strData
  //do what ever
  [aObj release]; //don't forget
}
```